# Problemas con ASP.NET CORE 2.0 y ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core, ado.net

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con **ASP.NET Core 2.0** y a la hora de añadir **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** no me aparece en la lista de elementos. Al hacer click botón derecho en la raíz del proyecto -> agregar -> nuevo elemento -> Datos, únicamente me aparece: "Archivo JSON","Archivo de esquema JSON","Archivo XML"
¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Revista [esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47372593) a ver si te ayuda

Comment: Por favor, amplía más tu pregunta para poder entender mejor cual es tu problema.  También añade **código**. Cuanta más información des, mas fácil será ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh, lo he intentado pero nada... El caso es que si creo un nuevo proyecto de Aplicación web ASP.NET (.NET FRAMEWORK) sí me da la opción de utilizar ADO, pero necesito hacerla con Core

Answer (score 0):

El soporte de Visual Studio 2017 para aplicaciones ASP.NET Core, **no incluye un diseñador gráfico** (wizard) para ADO.NET, como antes existía para aplicaciones ASP.NET Framework clásicas.

En tu caso, supongo que querrás crear un Modelo de datos para tu aplicación, a partir una base de datos existente.

En aplicaciones .NET Core, esto deberás hacerlo mediante **Entity Framework Core DataBase Fisrt** y sin diseñador gráfico, o sea, directamente desde la **Consola de administración de paquetes NuGet** con el comando **`Scaffold-DbContext`**.

Este sería un ejemplo:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "data source=*****;initial catalog=Northwind;user id=*****;password=*****" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Tables Region, Territories 
-DataAnnotations -Context "AppDbContext"
```

En el artículo [Entity Framework Core Database First en aplicaciones .NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/6/6/entity-framework-core-database-first-en-aplicaciones-net-mvc) podrás ver cómo crear tu Modelo de datos a partir de una Base de Datos existente.

También mírate esta pregunta de StackOverflow en inglés [Can't find ADO.net Entity Data Model template in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299332/cant-find-ado-net-entity-data-model-template-in-vs2017?rq=1) muy parecida a la tuya.